# jQuery Sidescroll, animate ScrollLeft

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What is wrong with this?

```
   $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
   if(delta>0){
        this.animate({scrollLeft: '+=300'},800,'easeOutQuad');
   }else if(delta<0){
        this.animate({scrollLeft: '-=300'},800,'easeOutQuad');
   }
```

my body width is `8000px` width the mouse wheel function i trigger the function if scroll down and up on mouse wheel. I want to scroll with the mouse wheel down and the body scroll `$(window).width()` to the right site and back...

Answer (score -1):

You need to wrap `this` inside event handler into jQuery function:

```
$(this).animate({scrollLeft: '+=300'}, 800, 'easeOutQuad');
```

because `this` is a HTMLBodyElement, it's not a jQuery instance, hence you can't use jQuery methods on it.

Comment: thanks for your fast answer. now i get this error:`TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'x.easing[this.easing](e,this.options.duration*e,0,1,this.options.duration)')`

Comment: Did you include easing plugin?

Comment: i don't know what you mean. this is my head: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-mousewheel-master/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">` jquery and mouse wheel works...

Comment: then, something work but ultra slow and only then when i reload fast.